# Gets the error without port number even when it is default port in tomcat?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat6

I have tomcat installed on my local machine. I see it in server.xml where I have below entry

```
   <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="${http.port}" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="${https.port}" 
           acceptCount="100"
           maxKeepAliveRequests="15"/>
```

where http.port value in catalina.properties is 8080 .

But every time I try to  access my application it url http://localhost/myApp I get error
           could not connect to localhost but it works fine  http://localhost:8080/myApp. I am not getting why it expects
           the port 8080 when it is already a default port? What should I do so that I do not have to mention port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `http://localhost/myApp` on the Address Bar of your Browser, the request always goes to <kbd>Port 80</kbd>, and not <kbd>Port 8080</kbd>. So the default is Port 80 here. For  `http://localhost/myApp` to work you need to install something like [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi).

Then you can configure it with the help of a connector like [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) or mod_proxy to use `http://localhost/myAppi`, instead of  `http://localhost:8080/myApp`. So that what ever request comes on <kbd>Port 80</kbd> can be diverted to <kbd>Port 8080</kbd> automatically.
Once you will download mod_jk, simply extract the file mod_jk.so to the modules folder of your Apache HTTP Server.

Hopefully the steps written here [How to Configure Apache HTTP Server with Apache Tomcat](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/webpages/configureht.html), might help you in doing that.

Comment: if simply change http.port value in catalina.properties to80 instead of 8080 .It should work right?

Comment: Had you tried doing that ? I guess it wont' work. I forgot as to why I had to do this thing, to launch the site, I am using now. That's what I did to make it work.

Comment: @MSach : Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: Are you on a Windows or Unix environment?

Comment: @ziggy : I am on Windows 7, but hope these steps might work for UNIX as well. Never tried it on UNIX though.

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows platform all you have to do is changing the port number in server.xml from 8080 to 80 and you are done.

The above is not true for Unix/Linux environments. Changing the port number might work on Windows but i think it might be slightly tricky on Unix/Solaris.

Under UNIX all ports <1024 are "privileged" ports. Only root may open a privileged port. It is still possible but keep in mind that it is not as simple as changing the port number when on Unix.

There are a number of workarounds for this.

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/how_to_run_tomcat_on

http://mihail.stoynov.com/2011/04/04/howto-start-tomcat-on-port-80-without-root-privileges/

http://java-notes.com/

http://www.klawitter.de/tomcat80.html

Comment: +1, I liked this information part, as once I tried it so hard to get my Tomcat work with Apache HTTP Server, LOL I know without proper guidance, how hard it is to make such things work, I went through the documentation like a million times, but seems like it's not that good related to this scenario, but your info is valuable :-)